# default.collection is not a function TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.collection is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import "./PlanScreen.css"
import db from '../../firebase';


const PlanScreen = () => {

    const [products, setProducts] =  useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection("products")
        .where("active", "==", true)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            const products = {};
            querySnapshot.forEach(async (productDoc) => {
                products[productDoc.id] = productDoc.data();
                const priceSnap = await productDoc.ref.collection("prices").get();
                priceSnap.docs.forEach((price) => {
                    products[productDoc.id].prices = {
                        priceId: price.id,
                        priceData: price.data(),
                    }
                })
            })
        }) ;
        setProducts(products)
    } , [])

    console.log(products)

  return (
    <div className='planScreen'></div>
  )
}

export default PlanScreen
```

I an making netflix clone with payment method . so i'm trying to use firebase 10 to update the project , however i cannot for the life of me get the useEffect right witht he current firebase 10 setup , any help please?